# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{xf'(x/(1-1/N))}{f(x/(1-1/N))}\ \mathsf dx$ as $N\to\infty$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> How can calculate this integral $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x) \frac{x f'\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)}{f\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)} dx$$ where $f(x)$ is a probability density function?

If there exist a function $g(x)$ such that $$\Bigg|f(x) \frac{x f'\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)}{f\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)}\Bigg|< g(x)$$ for all $N$, then 
 I can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. But can I calculate the integral without such an assumption? I am thinking maybe the probability function $f(x)$ has some characteristics that could help. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a mathematically rigorous answer, but too long for a comment. Change variables $x/(1-1/N)=\tau$. We get
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x) \frac{x f'\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)}{f\left(\frac{x}{1-1/N}\right)} dx=\lim_{N \to \infty} \left[(1-1/N)^2\int_{x=0}^{\infty}f((1-1/N)\tau) \frac{\tau f'\left(\tau\right)}{f\left(\tau\right)} d\tau\right]\ .
$$
Then morally the function $f((1-1/N)\tau)$ can be Taylor-expanded for $N\to\infty$ as
$$
f((1-1/N)\tau)\approx f(\tau)-\frac{1}{N}f'(\tau)\tau+\frac{1}{2N^2}f''(\tau)\tau^2-\ldots\ ,
$$
therefore the sought limit should be 
$$
\int_0^\infty d\tau\ \tau f'(\tau)=-\int_0^\infty d\tau\ f(\tau)=-1\ ,
$$
where one uses integration by parts, and assumes that $f(\tau)\to 0$ for $\tau\to\infty$ and $\int_0^\infty d\tau f(\tau)=1$ by normalization of the pdf. This result can be easily checked explicitly in a couple of cases, like $f(x)=\exp(-x)$ or $f(x)=\frac{2/\pi}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is really helpful. The only concern I have is using the Taylor expansion under the integral. Are we allowed to?

Comment: For that, you precisely need a 'mathematically rigorous answer' ;-) ..let's wait for the epsilon-deltas experts. Cheers

Comment: I agree. Generally, we cannot pull the limit into the integral.